Conjugation of a cycle preserves its length
$\sigma = (j_1\ j_2...j_r)$ is a cycle in $S_n$. $\tau$ is an arbitrary permutation in $S_n$. Show that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = \rho$ has the same length as $\sigma$. 
I found a proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3368435. 
I don't understand why we take $\tau(j_k)$ to do $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(\tau(j_k))=\tau\sigma(j_k)=\tau(j_{k+1})$ when we have to prove $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = \rho$ has the same length as $\sigma$. I know how to prove that conjugation preserves the cyclic type but it uses this fact that I can't fathom. I'm totally stuck.

What precisely don't you understand in the answer to the post you linked? (apart from the fact that I'd rather write $\sigma\color{red}=(j_1\ j_2...j_r)$).

I don't get where did this $\tau(j_k)$ came from... Shouldn't we prove that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = \tau(j_{k+1})$?

Thank you for the corrections, I edited the post.

$\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = \tau(j_{k+1})$ makes no sense. $\tau(j_{k+1})$ is an element.
$\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is a permutation, which this answer proved to coincide with the cycle $(\tau(j_1)\ \dots\ \tau(j_r))$.

Why do we apply this permutation exactly to the element $\tau(j_k)$?

Sorry for these dumb questions, I just started to study permutations...

You are right, we should apply it to every element. Those of the form $\tau(j_k)$ for some $k$ are moved as described, but we should also check that those of the form $\tau(i)$ for $i\ne j_1,\dots,j_r$ are not moved. Are you able to check that?

But why do we apply that to $\tau(j_k)$, not to $\sigma(j_k)$ or some other element of another cycle...

We apply it to each element of ${\tau(1),\dots,\tau(n)}$ (those of the form $\tau(j_k)$ and the other ones). This alternative enumeration of ${1,\dots,n}$ is chosen for its suitability in identifying this conjugate permutation. (Btw you didn't answer my "Are you able to check that?")

It seems to me I got it. $\forall j_i$ in any $\rho = (j_1, ..., j_n)  \ \exists j_k: j_i = \tau(j_k)$, right?
I think I'm able to check that the rest of elements are not moved. Let $k’$ be in ${1, \dots, n} \setminus {\tau(k_1), \dots, \tau(k_j)}$. $\tau$ is a bijection $ \implies \exists! k’’ \in {1, \dots, n}$ such that $\tau(k’’) = k’ \iff k’’ = \tau^{-1}(k’)$, so $k’’ \not\in {k_1, \dots, k_j}$, so it’s fixed by $\sigma$.
$( \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} \bigr) (k’)
= ( \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} \bigr) \tau(k’’)
= \tau \sigma (k’’) = \tau(k’’) = k’$.

Yes I also think you got it for the second part. Slight nitpicking for the first part: instead of "$\forall j_i$ in $\rho = (j_1, ..., j_n)  \ \exists j_k: j_i = \tau(j_k)$" I prefer: $\forall k''\in{\tau(k_1), \dots, \tau(k_n)}\ \exists j:k''=k_j.$

@mathemaniac: Write that in an answer and accept it, so this goes out of the unanswered stack.

Thank you Anne for your help, I united your comments to an answer.
Let $\sigma = (j_1 j_2 ... j_r)$ be a cycle in $S_n, \ \tau$ is an arbitrary permutation in $S_n$. Then $\forall j' \in \{\tau(j_1)...\tau(j_r)\} \ \exists k: j' = j_k. \\$
Then $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (j_i) = \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (\tau(j_k)) = \tau \sigma (j_k) = \tau(j_{k+1})$.
Now we just have to prove that those of the form $\tau(i)$ for $i \notin \{j_1,…,j_r\}$ are not moved. Let $k′$ be in $\{1,…,n\}\setminus\{\tau(k_1),…,\tau(k_j)\}$. $\tau$ is a bijection $\implies \exists!k′′ \in \{1,…,n\}$ such that $\tau(k′′)=k′\iff k′′=\tau^{−1}(k′)$, so $k′′\notin \{k_1,…,k_j\}$, so it’s fixed by $\sigma \ . (\tau\sigma\tau^{−1})(k′)=(\tau\sigma\tau^{−1})\tau(k′′)=\tau\sigma(k′′)=\tau(k′′)=k'$
